# Not able to connect my microphone in Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I'm using a system on which there is no built-in microphone available, so I've connected my earphones. When I play video sounds, I can hear the audio, but when I try to speak, it's not getting my voice. When I checked my sounds inside the Input section, there is one device, but in my brave browser settings, it's showing me this message. *`Not allowed to use your microphone`* [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAgmj.png), and this is my sound setting [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsMAD.png).

After running this command, `sudo journalctl  --follow` gives me this output.

```
m [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]:38367 (any)
Apr 20 11:40:26 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114026.059054:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 130.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Apr 20 11:40:26 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114026.061221:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 130.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Apr 20 11:40:27 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114027.081735:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 131.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Apr 20 11:40:27 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114027.081809:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 131.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop NetworkManager[1042]: <info>  [1650435030.4136] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.14' (uid=0 pid=1042 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop whoopsie[2134]: [11:40:30] The default IPv4 route is: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop whoopsie[2134]: [11:40:30] Not a paid data plan: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop whoopsie[2134]: [11:40:30] Found usable connection: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/4
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop dbus-daemon[924]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop nm-dispatcher[24437]: req:1 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Apr 20 11:40:30 dev-desktop nm-dispatcher[24437]: req:1 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Apr 20 11:40:31 dev-desktop whoopsie[2134]: [11:40:31] online
Apr 20 11:40:32 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114032.126277:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(659)] Message 1 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost
Apr 20 11:40:32 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16207:16207:0420/114032.127316:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
Apr 20 11:40:32 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16207:16207:0420/114032.129680:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(227)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
Apr 20 11:40:38 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114038.906652:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 132.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
Apr 20 11:40:38 dev-desktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[15722]: [16146:16146:0420/114038.907159:ERROR:CONSOLE(1)] "[Shields]: Can't request shields panel data for tabId: 132.  Error: No tab url specified", source: chrome-extension://mnojpmjdmbbfmejpflffifhffcmidifd/out/brave_extension_background.bundle.js (1)
```

Comment: Disconnect your earphone. In a terminal window, observe `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you connect your earphone.

Comment: How did you install Brave? If snap you need to enable additional permissions.

Comment: Hello @ChanganAuto I think it allow me to listen but not to speak and I've installed it  via apt pakage manager

Comment: Hello @waltinator Yes I've followed what you said and it's giving me some logs I've provided in my my question

Comment: Did you reconnect between 09:14:01 and 09:17:01? I see no 'phone connection. How is it "connected"? Do you need to adjust the volume in " my sounds inside Input section there is one device"?

Comment: Hello. I will ask the one no one has. Are you sure this device has a microphone?

Comment: Hello @David yes I'm using my regular earphone which I use for regularly for my all meetings but my pc does not connecting my earphone microphone because of that I connect with two devices please help.

Comment: Hello @waltinator I've provided my input device [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsMAD.png) and it's volume is at max level

Comment: Hello @waltinator I've edited my question please check this `sudo journalctl  --follow` command output.

Comment: Hello @waltinator can you check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493292/trouble-detecting-both-speakers-and-microphone-with-combined-trrs-jack-on-ubuntu) it's related to this question.