# Trouble Detecting Both Speakers and Microphone with Combined TRRS Jack on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, audio-jack

I'm facing an issue on **Ubuntu [20.04](/questions/tagged/20.04)** with my earphones that have a combined **TRRS** jack. When I plug the jack into the green port, Ubuntu recognizes the speakers but not the microphone. When I plug it into the pink port, it detects the microphone but not the speakers.

Is there a way to make **Ubuntu** recognize both the speakers and the microphone when using a single jack? I've tried adjusting settings in the Sound menu, but it seems to only recognize one function at a time. Are there any specific configurations, drivers, or adapters I should be looking into?

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!